# Find all installed AppX apps from .NET Framework, display icons, launch them

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-metro, appx

I have a launcher tool written in C# .NET Winforms Framework 4.7.2. I want to add the ability for the user to find and launch "Metro" style apps (now called AppX apps, or UWP apps?).

From what I've been able to piece together, I can use PowerShell to get a list these installed apps via [Get-AppxPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2022-ps). That gives my app each one's full name, which can then be used with [GetPackageInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/appmodel/nf-appmodel-getpackageinfo) via Interop to get information about the app, like its icon location. My app can also launch the app via [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) (again, Interop) using the format:

`Shell:AppsFolder\NAME_OF_THE_APP_PACKAGE!App`

I'd like to avoid PowerShell for the initial listing. I see UWP's [PackageManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager?view=winrt-22621) class but is that available from a .NET Framework assembly, or must I somehow call it from a UWP assembly? (I tried adding a UWP class library to my solution and referencing it from my .NET Framework assembly, but it didn't like that, unsurprisingly.)

Comment: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)

Answer (score 0):

My colleagues built a free app that lists all the packages from the machine and allows you to launch an external EXE inside the container of a specific app container.

You can see the code on GitHub, hope it helps:
https://github.com/Caphyon/hover